# Problema ao receber, via Intent, um arquivo compartilhado por outro app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estou com problemas ao abrir o arquivo compartilhado via `Intent`.
Consigo receber corretamente o caminho para o arquivo mas o meu *app* encerra a execução.
E infelizmente não estou conseguindo capturar o erro gerado.
Meu código:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    Log.d("Artur", "Action: "+action);
    Log.d("Artur", "Type: "+type);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("*/*".equals(type)) {
            Uri arqUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (arqUri != null) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    Log.d("Artur", "vai abrir: "+arqUri.getPath());
                    fis = openFileInput(arqUri.getPath());  //<----ERRO
                    Log.d("Artur", "Leu: "+(byte)fis.read());

                    fis.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("Artur", "FileNotFoundException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Artur", "IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arquivo nao identificado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Também tenho outra dúvida.
Somente consigo receber um arquivo se for usada a opção de "compartilhar com" no app chamador.
Eu gostaria de que meu programa se tornasse o padrão para a abertura desse tipo de arquivo, que possui a extensão RLC, por exemplo: "config.rlc".
Assim basta definir ele como padrão para ler esse arquivo, ao receber um por email ou outra fonte bastaria um toque sobre ele para que meu programa seja executado.
Como é com um editor de textos, pdf, visualizador de imagem e outros.
Obrigado.

Editado.

Resolvi o problema de abertura, erro de digitação:

> fis = new FileInputStream(arqUri.getPath());

Mas agora estou tento o erro de arquivo não existe.

Editado:
Consegui resolver a segunda parte do meu problema.
Faltava esse bloco:

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rlc" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Agora continuo com o problema de arquivo não existe.

```
                    Uri arqUri = intent.getData();

                Log.d("Artur", "arqUri: " + arqUri);
                if (arqUri != null) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis;
                        String caminho = arqUri.getPath();
                        Log.d("Artur", "Caminho: " + caminho);
                        File file = new File(caminho);
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                        Log.d("Artur", "Leu: " + (byte) fis.read());

                        fis.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("Artur", "FileNotFoundException");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //return;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("Artur", "IOException");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //return;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Não esqueça que para poder partilhar um arquivo entre aplicações este tem de estar num local(path) que possa ser acedido pelas duas aplicações.

Comment: O arquivo esta na pasta de Downloads do telefone.

Comment: Qual é o resultado de `arqUri.getPath()`?

Comment: /sdcard/Download/a.rlc

Comment: Retorno do erro: FileNotFoundException:/sdcard/Download/maximo.rlc: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Achei a resposta aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527767/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Comment: O lance é que na versão API23 ou mais não basta das declarações feitas no manifest.

Comment: Se você tivesse dado essa informação(Permission denied e Api23) teria sido possível responder.

Comment: Falha minha, sem duvida. E só tenho a agradecer a ajuda. Agora consigo abrir o arquivo quando ele esta salvo. Mas tenho outro erro quando ele é um anexo de um email: android open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: É melhor fazer outra pergunta focada apenas nesse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Neste código exposto parece que está faltando, no mínimo, a solicitação para leitura no armazenamento do dispositivo, pois do contrário sempre ocorrerá o erro de permissão. Segue sugestão de correção:

```
// Storage Permissions variables
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

    //persmission method.
     public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have read or write permission
        int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }
```

Solução encontrata em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied